# Regression with dummy variable multiplied by another

Tags: r, lm

What is the difference between approach 1 and approach 2 below?
I was thinking that '**I()**' will allow us to multiple 2 variables and to not included interaction, but here it is not working as expected. Do I undertsand correct that the 2nd approach takes into account also three 0 (non-USA)? So the model is build on 6 points instead of 3 - can we somehow fix it?

```r
df <- data.frame(
                 Salary=c(5, 1:2,4,1:2),
                 Variable1=c(500,490,501,460,490,505),
                 Variable2=c(5,10,0,3,17,40),
                 Country=c(rep("USA",3),rep("RPA",3)),
                 Dummy_USA=c(rep(1,3), rep(0,3))
)

# Approach 1
summary(lm(Salary~Variable1, df%>% filter(Country=="USA")))

# Approach 2
summary(lm(Salary~I(Variable1*Dummy_USA), df))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the second version simply regresses the vector `c(5, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2)` on the vector `c(500, 490, 501, 0, 0, 0)`. This is very different from the first version, which regresses the vector `c(5, 1, 2)` in the vector `c(500, 490, 501)`.

If you want to use a dummy variable you could either pass it to the `subset` argument of `lm` or the `weights` argument.

```r
with(df, summary(lm(Salary ~ Variable1, subset = Dummy_USA == 1)))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Salary ~ Variable1, subset = Dummy_USA == 1)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>       1       2       3 
#>  1.6847 -0.1532 -1.5315 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) -104.7928   131.8453  -0.795    0.572
#> Variable1      0.2162     0.2653   0.815    0.565
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 2.282 on 1 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.3992, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.2017 
#> F-statistic: 0.6644 on 1 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.5646
```

or

```r
with(df, summary(lm(Salary ~ Variable1, weights = Dummy_USA)))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Salary ~ Variable1, weights = Dummy_USA)
#> 
#> Weighted Residuals:
#>       1       2       3       4       5       6 
#>  1.6847 -0.1532 -1.5315  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) -104.7928   131.8453  -0.795    0.572
#> Variable1      0.2162     0.2653   0.815    0.565
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 2.282 on 1 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.3992, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.2017 
#> F-statistic: 0.6644 on 1 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.5646
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

To make this easier to refer to let us refer to Salary and Variable1
as y and x respectively and let b0 and b1 be the intercept and slope.  Then
the first `lm` does not involve y[4], y[5], y[6] but the second one does.

In particular, the first `lm` is minimizing the following over b0 and b1

```
(y[1] - b0 - b1 * x[1])^2 + (y[2] - b0 - b1 * x[2])^2 + (y[3] - b0 - b1 * x[3])^2
```

whereas the second one is minimizing that plus

```
(y[4] - b0)^2 + (y[5] - b0)^2 + (y[6] - b0)^2
```